# YouTube and SoundCloud embedding is now enabled

Tags: discussion

It is now possible to embed YouTube (audio/video) and SoundCloud (audio) clips in posts here.

Here's how:

1. Upload your audio to the respective site.
2. When composing your post, paste the URL to the uploaded audio in the body, on a line by itself, like so:

   > I'm trying to reproduce this performance...
   >
   > http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vin9sapwkRU

   or

   > I can't quite capture this sound...
   >
   > http://soundcloud.com/cyrilic/nintendo-super-mario-bros-ground-theme
3. After you save the post, it will be rendered with an embedded player of the appropriate type:

   [image: soundcloud player]

You can see some examples of this in action at

- [How important is it to have an EQ pedal in your chain?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/how-important-is-it-to-have-an-eq-pedal-in-your-chain)
- [How do I play this tab of No More Sorrow's Live version](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/how-do-i-play-this-tab-of-no-more-sorrows-live-version) (rotted away)

#### Head on over [to the main site](http://music.stackexchange.com) and try it out!

Comment: Thanks! This is a great addition.

Comment: yeeepe i asked for this feature :D

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant!

Comment: @Brahadeesh I don't think so. I think the featured tag expired at some point but did not show up as an edit and my edit was the next one after it expired.

Comment: @Brahadeesh they do that naturally now, but it shows up as a community edit

Answer (score 10):

Please note that when you sign up for [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com) (it's free!) none of the audio samples you upload will be public by default.

**You must manually enable the clips you upload to be visible to the public for them to work here!**

So when uploading to SoundCloud, look for the public / private toggle, and make sure it is enabled.

[image]

After uploading, this can also be toggled on the track page by clicking the "share" button on the audio widget itself.

[image]

The share dialog will indicate whether the track is currently public or private; click **Make track public** to ensure it can be shared here.

[image]

Once you do that, simply paste the URL to the SoundCloud page for the audio clip on a line by itself, like so:

`http://soundcloud.com/jatwood/fallout-opening-theme-maybe`

*this isn't enabled on meta, but works on the main site :)*