# https for SoundCloud

Tags: bug, status-completed

The [SoundCloud integration](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/245/2125) on our SE only works with http:

https://soundcloud.com/georgeharrison/your-eyes-sitar-solo
(doesn't work)

http://soundcloud.com/georgeharrison/your-eyes-sitar-solo
(works)

Comment: Just a heads up that I have passed this along to the SE dev team.

Answer (score 6):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next build (1995)

Comment: We appreciate it!