# Soundcloud embedding - new issues?

Tags: bug, status-review

I'm not sure whether I'm doing this wrong or it's just not working for me.

We've been able to embed Soundcloud links for a while now - [YouTube and SoundCloud embedding is now enabled](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled) even though there was a transition issue with https - [https for SoundCloud](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/https-for-soundcloud)

…but I inlined one this morning & it doesn't show to me, it's just a link, in [Why are doubled vocals usually panned left and right?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109688/why-are-doubled-vocals-usually-panned-left-and-right/109701#109701)

Is this confirmable by others, or is it just me?
Bug, feature or human error?

Further tests
My Soundcloud uploads are set to Public by default - I have to manually change if I want Private, so that's not it.

***Edit 2023 to lift this back to the top.***
Issue still exists. New posts do not embed. Existing posts retain the embedded view.

New - [Is there an audio mistake in the Carole King You've Got A Friend YouTube video?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/131381/is-there-an-audio-mistake-in-the-carole-king-youve-got-a-friend-youtube-video)

Existing - [How can I get a violin sound from my electric guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24941/how-can-i-get-a-violin-sound-from-my-electric-guitar)

*Two years is a bit of a stretch to stay "in review". Should I elevate this to main meta?*

I did raise this on main Meta, but it got bounced back to here - [SoundCloud embeds broken on 'Music: Practice & Theory'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378615/soundcloud-embeds-broken-on-music-practice-theory)

Comment: Re: deleted test below - I don't think it's meant to work on Meta, I think you have to try it on main. [Jeff Atwood note on original announcement confirms this]

Comment: I wondered if the problem arose from having a YouTube link preceding the SoundCloud link. Nope. Created a question on the main site with only a SoundCloud link and nothing else, and the embedding failed.

Comment: Checking a few posts, I also failed to see any embedded players on [existing posts with Soundcloud URL](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3asoundcloud).

Comment: FWIW, I also failed to find the relevant JS scripts to convert the links to embedded players. As for why [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2720) still shows the embedded player, I believe because there's no revision since 2011 and the rendered HTML page was saved in the database. I just did a science (*please reject them*) and the same question failed to render the embedded player after I suggested an edit.